# Error while cmaking curlpp

Tags: cmake, curlpp

I am trying to cmake [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/) using Cmake version 3.4.1 and I get an error in cmake saying: " Error in configuration process [...]". So all I did is in cmake-gui open the curlpp source (version 0.7.3), selected the destination folder and chose mingw. Here is the output in the gui http://pastebin.com/1gKyqd32.

It said Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/c++/libraries/curlpp_built/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
[CMakeOutput.log](http://pastebin.com/ScZZh56n)

I setup CMake correctly and I could compile glfw library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the relevant part of the output

> CMake Error at src/utilspp/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_subdirectory):
>     add_subdirectory given source "singleton" which is not an existing
>     directory.

The project's CMakeLists.txt in src/utilspp is broken.

The bug is already reported in curlpp's issue tracker:
https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/issues/7

You can work around this bug by removing line 4 from `src/utilspp/CMakeLists.txt` it should contain something like `add_subdirectory(singleton)`. If you are lucky, everything works; but other errors might pop up.

Comment: They didn't answer back. I should use binary files but there aren't out there. So is there anyway I can get this binaries from an old repo or any way for me to obtain them?

Comment: @Andy Updated my answer, maybe that's enough. Maybe you have to wait for someone to fix it within the project.